# When running VC 6.0 C++, error C2146 keep occuring

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // your code goes here
    class Solution {
    public:
        vector<vector<int> > combinationSum(vector<int>& candidates, int target);
        vector<vector<int> > combinationSum(vector<int>& candidates, int target)
        {
            vector<vector<int> > res;
            vector<int> out;
            combinationSumDFS(candidates, target, 0, out, res);
            return res;
        }
        void combinationSumDFS(vector<int>& candidates, int target, int start, vector<int>& out, vector<vector<int> >& res)
        {
            if (target < 0)
                return;
            if (target == 0) {
                res.push_back(out);
                return;
            }
            for (int i = start; i < candidates.size(); ++i) {
                out.push_back(candidates[i]);
                combinationSumDFS(candidates, target - candidates[i], i, out, res);
                out.pop_back();
            }
        }
    } yoyo;
    vector<int> aa = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
    vector<vector<int> > restl = [[]];
    restl = yoyo.combinationSum(&aa, 3);
    court << restl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above, I got

```
F:\VC6.0\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin\combinationSum.cpp(10) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'combinationSum'".
```

Comment: Perhaps because you declare `combinationSum` *twice* in the same class?

Comment: Also please reindent your code to make it consistent. It's ***very*** hard to read it as it is now.

Comment: There are also other errors you should be getting, including one that makes me think that you have skipped some sections of your text-book (or skipped class). The unary `&` operator, as used in e.g. `&aa`, results in a *pointer* not a reference. In your case the type of `&aa` is `std::vector<int>*`.

Comment: There must be a whole bunch of ther errors - for instance, you use `[` and `]` where you should use  `{` and `}`, and there are type errors.

Comment: And then there's the "elephant in the room": VC++ 6.0? I used it at work when it was new, 23 years ago. It barely supported the first C++ standard, which was ratified the same year VC++ 6.0 was release, and it had so many quirks and problems that I'm surprised it was even workable. There's simply no valid excuse to be using it today, and any possible school that insists on it are almost as bad as those still using Turbo C++. These days there are free (as in no cost) *very* good compilers as well as good (and free) environments.

Comment: Are there suggestions for free and nice environments?

Comment: @Existence Visual Studio 2019 community edition

Comment: [Visual Studio Code with the C++ plugin and MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) seems popular. For Windows in general, MinGW as compiler then there are many nice editors and a couple of [IDE's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), like for example code:blocks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many errrors:

- The first declaration `vector<vector<int> > combinationSum(vector<int>& candidates, int target);` is pointless and wrong, just remove it.
- `vector<int> aa = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]` is wrong. An initialisation list must be delimited with `{}`: `vector<int> aa = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`
- `[[]]` doesn't make sense, just drop it
- `yoyo.combinationSum(&aa, 3);`  is wrong, it should be `yoyo.combinationSum(aa, 3);` because the vector is passsed by reference, so no need of pointers here.
- There is a typo in `court << restl`, it should be `cout << restl`, but anyway there is no output operator `<<` for vectors, you have to loop through the vector yourself, I leave this as an exercise to you.

Comment: Thanks for your fine suggestions. Then I encountered the following. F:\VC6.0\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin\combinationSum.cpp(26) : error C2552: 'aa' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list. Any ideas for solving this problem?

Comment: @Existence this is because Visual Studio 6 is antiquateed and follows only a very old C++ standard. Consider switching to a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: okay, but it seems it's a bit complicated.

Comment: I will try it later again.